# Incompatible types in assignment of strings in linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, stack, variable-assignment

The purpose of this program is to convert an infix expression to postfix, then evaluate the values using linked lists. I've tried using strcpy to no avail, either that or I missed something. I need to use a string here because when the numbers reach double digits it will not be pushed to the stack. Any help on this one? I tried to use functions so that the only a few usable ones that I will call in my main program. I also have a separate set of functions for my queue, but once i figure out how to fix this, I can easily apply it to the other functions.

```
    struct StackNode { 
    char SData[126]; //this one here
    struct StackNode *next; 
}; 

struct StackNode* StackNewNode(char SData) //i dont know what to put in the char SData, is it a *? 
{                                          //because it produces an invalid conversion error.

    struct StackNode *stackNode = (struct StackNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct StackNode)); 
    stackNode->SData = SData; 
    stackNode->next = NULL; 
    return stackNode; 
}  

char topstack(struct StackNode *root) 
{ 
    if (root == NULL) 
    {
        return 0; 
    }
    return root->SData; 
} 

void push(struct StackNode **root, char SData) 
{ 
    struct StackNode *stackNode = StackNewNode(SData); 
    stackNode->next = *root; 
    *root = stackNode; 
    printf("\n%c pushed to stack\n", SData); 
} 

char pop(struct StackNode **root) 
{ 
    if (*root == NULL) 
    {
        return 0; 
    }
    struct StackNode *temp = *root; 
    *root = (*root)->next; 
    char pop = temp->SData; 
    free(temp); 
    printf("%c popped from stack\n", popped); 
    return pop; 
}
```

Comment: `char SData` is the value of a single character. You should pass a pointer to a `const char` array for `StackNewNode()` and where appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want a linked list of fixed-length strings.

If this is true, `StackNewNode` should use a `const char*` parameter type as input. Another possible way is to use a fixed-length string input using `char SData[126]`.

Moreover, the line `stackNode->SData = SData;` must be modified to make a string copy as strings are not usually copied using a simple assignment statement in C. The function [strcpy](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy) in string.h is made for that, but since your destination buffer is a fixed-length string of size 126, it is better to use [strncpy](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strncpy).

Additionally, `topstack` must also return a string-like type. One way to do that is to return a "const char*" type. But be careful: if your node is free, the string returned will no longer be valid. So you may want to make a copy of that string using [strdup](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup) and then let the function that call `topstack` free the returned string. Another way would be to add a new parameter `char* SData` to `topstack` and copy the content of your linked-list node in `SData` in the body of the function (in this case it assume that SData is allocated by the function that call `topstack` and that the string have a size big enough to contain the string content in the linked-list node).

Finally, the same thing apply for `pop`. However, the string has to be duplicated since the function free the linked list node. Please note that returning the value is probably not needed as the `topstack` function can already do it. Also, `popped` is not defined and should probably be replaced by `pop`.

Comment: Thanks for this, ill keep this in mind. As for the pop not defined, that was my fault.

Comment: No problem, consider reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it solve your issues.